# Fastest Way to Find and Link to a CP on a Page?

Tags: 2013, dynamic-linking, linking

I have three linking related questions followed by some background.

After explaining SDL Tridion linking behavior, I often get asked, **"as a Content Author, how do I link to a specific page?"**

1. **Knowing a URL, what's the fastest way to link to a CP on that page as a CMS user?**

   I'm thinking:

   1. Start XPM in Staging
   2. Click on the CP or open the page's form view
   3. Jump to that location in the CME

   Where Used is about as fast. Am I missing a faster approach while *creating* the link?
2. I *think* (or think I heard) Page URIs are actually managed as of 2013 SP1 in rich text format areas. Is that right and would page TCM IDs be Content Portable?
3. **If so, what about links *across* publications?** I'm thinking this *won't* work--don't all publication IDs in the context of a Publication *have* to be the same?

As an implementation option, I can imagine a Custom URL or other extension that literally converts a Staging or Production URL into a Component Link.

### Background

SDL Tridion component linking depends on three things:

1. **The template** for the *linking* Component (make `<tcdl>` link)
2. Template **priorities**
3. The **proximity** of the linked Component as a Component Presentation embedded (dynamically or statically) on a published Tridion Page (which [I've tried to summarize](http://www.createandbreak.net/2012/05/how-to-remember-tridion-dynamic-linking.html))

### Authoring Approaches

My recommendations have included:

- **Link to components on pages**, typically the ones that contain page content ("SEO" or "main" editorial component)
- Use **naming conventions** to match pages and these components, possibly helped with the event system or Page Types that use the `%P%` placeholder (so copied components have the page's name)
- Use **similarly-named folders** and **search**
- Have developers **set template priority** so a "main" CP has high priority to represent the page you want to link to

*Hopefully authors will be familiar with their content model and be able to find the right components, but I don't always get to revisit an implementation after training and design.*

Any other explanations or implementation approaches? I'm not necessarily avoiding author-controlled page linking, but with multiple child publications, I can't see how you'd pick which publication to link to (page "master" publications?). Needing to somehow handle such links in child publications seems hackish as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I really get your questions, but let me try and give an answer to numbers 1-3.

## 1.

If you know the URL you can use that in your `href` attribute, if you know the URI, you can use a Dynamic Page Link, for instance with TCDL:

```xml
<tcdl:Link type="Page" origin="tcm:5-199-64" destination="tcm:5-206-64" 
       templateURI="tcm:0-0-0" linkAttributes="" textOnFail="true" 
       addAnchor="" variantId="">Home</tcdl:Link>
```

## 2.

2013 SP1 allows an xlink to any item, so that would include Pages and yes any xlink is a managed link and thus can be Content Ported.

## 3.

Cross Publication linking is not supported on the CM or CD side, however it is know to work on the CD side (because that is not in a CM context, so you can link to any valid URI from any Publication).

Comment: You got the questions but I forgot to emphasize that the ones asking the main question are content authors. I'll update the question.

Comment: Would Item Selector or similar extensions then need to use RTF to properly store the xlinks for #2?